# Microsoft Surface pro 1 local admin account issue

Tags: domain, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Surface pro 1 joined to a domain and I am having trust relationship issue. The local admin account is disabled, I disabled the secure boot from BIOS and tried booting Hiren CD and USB but with no luck. I cannot boot from any external devices.

I can login by normal account without any administrative privilege.

Comment: This sounds like a restriction put in place by your IT department. What do they say about it?

Comment: "I cannot boot from any external devices." - This means there is no way to enable the built-in Administrator account on your machine.  If you need Administrator access on your machine you should contact your domain Administrator.

Comment: the problem is the trust relation ship due to the tablet name has been deleted from domain

Comment: is there away to reset the tablet by using hardware buttons or any way to reformat the tablet

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for contributing, we solved the issue by removing the SSD and reformatted on external PC then reconnected it, it is bit far solution and extreme but that was our only way. Thank you gain